# How to remove Link To Category from Redactor

Tags: redactor, richtext

Is there a way to remove the 2 Craft specific menu items from Redactor's Link menu without losing access to the "Insert link" menu item?

Removing the Link button in the redactor configs is too draconian as I don't want to lose access to the basic Insert and Unlink functions previously in that menu.

I've dug into the src, and the only hook/event I can find related to the redactor settings allows addition of menu items to the Links menu, but not removal of the Craft added "Link to an Entry" and "Link to a Category".

[image: Rich text field with link menu exposed with menu items crossed out.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way to do this natively in Craft.

Maybe you could pull it off with combination of https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss and/or https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcjs and manipulate the DOM directly.

Or maybe by going from the Redactor site and listening to their [click](https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/callbacks/events/#callback-click) event.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, this is very easy to do in Craft 3!

https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/issues/146#issuecomment-501862773

Using a custom module, you can implement code similar to this...

```php
use craft\redactor\events\RegisterLinkOptionsEvent;
use craft\redactor\Field as RedactorField;
use yii\base\Event;

// Remove "Link to..." Redactor links
Event::on(
    RedactorField::class,
    RedactorField::EVENT_REGISTER_LINK_OPTIONS,
    function(RegisterLinkOptionsEvent $event) {

        // Only apply to a specific Redactor config
        if ('Message.json' == $event->sender->redactorConfig) {

            // Remove Craft's injected links
            $event->linkOptions = [];

        }

    }
);
```

Answer (score -2):

In craft->app->fieldtypes->RichTextFieldType.php there is a function called _getLinkOptions. In there if you just return an empty array, there will only be the option to link to a URL.

Comment: Please do NOT do this. Any updates you make to the `craft/app` folder could be removed when you run Craft updates. Brad's answer about using a plugin is the best solution.

Comment: Sometimes people need a solution. If you have control of updates and keep track of what you've changed it's really not a big deal. Can people be trusted to use their own discretion?