# How to remove category link from redactor links but leave assets and entry link

Tags: plugin-development, redactor, modules

This is a follow up from [How to remove Link To Category from Redactor](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/17567/how-to-remove-link-to-category-from-redactor).

I've been able to setup the module and remove all links with this:

```
Event::on(
  RedactorField::class,
  RedactorField::EVENT_REGISTER_LINK_OPTIONS,
  function(RegisterLinkOptionsEvent $event) {

          $event->linkOptions = [];
  }
);
```

Which removes all Craft links, but how do I remove the categories links only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, your are overriding `$event->linkOptions` which contains an array with all options to an empty array with `$event->linkOptions = []`.

First, add the below to your module and refresh any page on your site so you see what you are working with:

```php
Event::on(
  RedactorField::class,
  RedactorField::EVENT_REGISTER_LINK_OPTIONS,
  function(RegisterLinkOptionsEvent $event) {

    Craft::dd($event->linkOptions);
  }
);
```

In the array you saw above, you want to remove the object containing a `'elementType' => 'craft\\elements\\Category'`.

You can do this by searching `$event->linkOptions` for `craft\\elements\\Category`, remove it but still returning the rest of the options.

Here's one way of doing so:

```php
Event::on(
    \craft\redactor\Field::class,
    \craft\redactor\Field::EVENT_REGISTER_LINK_OPTIONS,
    function(\craft\Redactor\events\RegisterLinkOptionsEvent $event) {
        $defaultOptions = $event->linkOptions;

        // Search for category element
        $categoryLink = \craft\helpers\ArrayHelper::where($defaultOptions, 'elementType', 'craft\\elements\\Category');

        // If present, remove the option and return the rest
        $event->linkOptions = \craft\helpers\ArrayHelper::without($defaultOptions, key($categoryLink));
    }
);
```

Comment: That works, and learned a bit more about setting op a Module, thanks!